# How can I tell which version of a gem is currently active?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have several rhc gem versions installed.  rhc is a command line client for openshift which is RedHat's cloud.

The gem adds a couple of shell commands, like `rhc-chk`, `rhc-ctl-domain`, `rhc-create-app`, `rhc-ctl-app`, etc.

With the following command I can see which versions of the gem I have installed:

```
gem list rhc
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rhc (0.84.15, 0.81.14, 0.79.5)
```

Is there some command to find out which particular version is currently active, or I can safely assume that is the last one the one I'm using?

to be more precise, I mean if there's something like this:

```
gem list rhc --active
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rhc 0.81.14
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the highest numbered version is active unless you specifically request a lower version. Typically this is done by locking with a declaration in `Gemfile`, the `gem` import call, or the generated `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Or from the command line by specifying the version as the first argument surrounded with underscores: `gem_command _version_ other args`.